# How to make a typescript type for an object that must have nullable property values?

Tags: typescript

**Motivation:**
For debugging purposes I want to make a utility function that takes an object of possibly null values, and produces an error message if any of the values are null.

**Question:**
How can I make a typescript type that accepts any object where all of the values have the possibility of being null? I'd like a type error if I accidentally give this function an object that has a value that can't be null.

**What I've tried:**

```js
interface CheckNullsDictionary {
    [id: string]: any; 
}

function anyNullErrorMessage(dict: CheckNullsDictionary): string | null {
  // Accepting an object is nice because the error message this produces will 
  // reference the keys that are null.
}
```

This is almost what I want, but I want it to be a type error if i'm giving it an object
with values that can't be null, because why check at all then?
Example:

```js
const name = "dustin";
const address: string | null = lookupAddressFor(name);
const phoneNumber: string | null = lookupPhoneNumberFor(name);

// Typescript can see that these are nullable, so it should
// allow this call.
if (anyNullErrorMessage({address, phoneNumber}) {

}

// Typescript knows that it's impossible for name to be null,
// so I want this to be a type error
if (anyNullErrorMessage({name}) {
  //react to the error
}
```

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you want, but I think `type MyType = { [key: string]: any }` should suffice?

Comment: It does work, but I'm wondering if the typescript type checker is powerful enough to tell me that I'm needlessly checking a value that cannot be null in the first place. 

Not for practical reasons -- I just think it would be really cool.